# Akka IO.TCP with Json

Tags: sockets, scala, tcp, akka

I've written a client and server using akka.io.tcp and I'm having a problem when reading the messages sent by the client.
I've used json to send the messages. 
In the client side, I write the message this way:

```
connection ! Write(ByteString(msgString))
```

In the server side I have the following:

```
override def receive: Receive = {
  case Received(data) => listener ! Json.parse(data.utf8String)
  case PeerClosed => {
    context stop self
  }
}
```

The problem is akka is reading more than one message at a time, so I get an invalid Json. 
Is there a way to make akka read just one message at a time?

Comment: I may be wrong here, but I believe that part is going to be on you.  You will have to write the logic that knows when one request ends and another begins and handle holding onto incomplete requests and pairing them up with the rest of them when it comes in.  I believe in Netty terminology, this would be a FrameDelimiter in the pipeline, but I don't believe there is an analogous feature currently in Akka Tcp for this (although I might be wrong).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Akka's TCP module is (and is designed to be) very "low level", so we're not providing any kind of frame delimiters. You should treat it more like an TCP level building block you then have to build your stuff on.

In your example, the Actor would have to aggregate the incoming chunks of data, and detect when a json document is "complete", then trigger the unmarshalling.

The idea of providing something out of the box for this is quite compelling... I'll ask the guys what our plans are for supporting these kinds of use cases.

Still, I hope this helped!

Comment: ok. now I have another doubt: I'm receiving more than one message at a time. is it possible to receive half the message for example?

Comment: Yes, as stated before, the Akka Tcp code has not idea about frame delimiters and thus sends whatever it has regardless of if to you it's a full chunk of data or not.  You need to piece all of this together on your own.

Comment: What you can do to solve this is to aggregate all chunks, then on each receive try to check where a JSON document is ending (if it is ending), and then extract that part from your "aggregated string", to then `Json.parse` it. Or you could introduce another actor which would do the splitting, and send _full_ json strings to a "parser actor"... Just some ideas :-)

Comment: I'll do that. Thank you very much. I'm having another issue where the client sends a lot of messages and the server stops receiving and does not throw any exception... Do you know what can cause this or how to track what is happening to solve this issue?

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the code. Can you post an example (either here on on the akka-user mailing list)?

Comment: Here is the server: http://pastebin.com/15LJHB6Y and here is the client: http://pastebin.com/QWiUwt64 BaseActor extends Actor and I've implemented the unhandled function. I didn't implemented your suggestion to buffer the message until it receive the end of it yet.

Comment: `so we're not providing any kind of frame delimiters` for my opinion it is very bad. With java I can create socket object and read from input stream untill I get `-1` as byte value. Simple and effective. I saw akka source code a bit and it uses java socket underhood with same `-1` "byte value" logic, why do not send a specific message to handler actor when socket  frame data is completed?